# Function which creates the sequence 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I was wondering how to map the set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to the sequence $1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. I thought it would be easy, but I was only able to obtain an answer through trial and error.

For a function $f \colon \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, we have that

$f(x) = x \bmod 3$ gives the numbers $1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, \ldots$

$f(x) = (x \bmod 3) + 1$ gives the numbers $2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, \ldots$

After a bit of experimenting, I finally found that

$f(x) = ((x + 2) \bmod 3) + 1$ gives the numbers $1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$

More generally, if I want to map the set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to the sequence $\{1, 2, \ldots, n, 1, 2, \ldots, n, \ldots\}$, I need to use the function

$$f(x) = ((x + n - 1) \bmod n) + 1$$

I was only able to come to this result by trial and error. I was not able to find a solution to this relatively simple question online (although perhaps my search terms were off).

How would one come to this result in a more systematic way?

Comment: Very good question. In general, a lot of things we can find by trial and error, and after we find it we may discover some simpler way to obtain it, such as dxiv's answer. But I can bet that dxiv first found it by trial and error also, if he/she didn't already see it before... To further hone your trial and error skills, try to find a simple formula for $1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,...$ and $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,...$. =)

Comment: Oh and I should say that if you're interested in a **program**, the easiest way to repeat any sequence in general is to use a list. In my first exercise, `def f(n): return [2,1,2,3][n%4]` would finish the job quickly and cleanly.

Comment: In general it appears you want to map the positive integers to themselves.  Edit your question.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: The notation $f : S \to T$ does **not** imply that $f$ must be a **surjection** from $S$ onto $T$. The question is wrong only in calling the desired output **sequence** a **set**.

Comment: What is the $n + 1, n + 2, \ldots, 2n, \ldots$ doing in the "More generally" sentence? It doesn't match the rest of the description, which seems to say you want a sequence $1, 2, \ldots n, 1, 2, \ldots n, \ldots$.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo on my part. It has been fixed.

Comment: I just want to note here - since somehow no one has yet - that 'the function which repeats the pattern 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...' is a perfectly good definition of the function in its own right. Be careful not to confuse a _function_ with a _formula_ for the function.

Comment: You seem to be treading $mod$ as an operation, which is common in programming. I find it easier to think of it as a modifier (no pun intended) on equality/congruence. $a = b  \mod c$ means "under $\mod c$, $a = b$". Looking at it like that, $f(x) = x \mod 3$ gives both $1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0...$ *and* $1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3$, since (under $\mod 3$) 0 and 3 are equivalent.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "trial and error". That's the exact method by which a huge amount of mathematics is discovered.

Comment: Do not have reputation on this site to answer, please look at this OEIS entry: https://oeis.org/A010882

Comment: That's an interesting link, thank you!

Comment: Further to @AndrewPilser, the function you mean by $ x \bmod n $ is the minimal non-negative residue (remainder) of $ x $ on division by $ n $. In computing you need to make sure you know how your platform (language+compiler) interprets this, though usually you will be OK. In mathematics it is true that the relation of equality modulo $ n $ is more commonly meant, but there is nothing wrong with wanting a name for this function. Given this function, the general solution is more elegantly expressed as $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Comment: The way you arrived at a solution by trial and error is a lot more useful to your mathematical development than any ‘_systematic_’ way of finding it on line would have been. If you reflect on how adding something before or after applying $ \bmod n $ affects the function, perhaps drawing or imagining the graph of it, you will improve your understanding of how to construct such functions.

Answer (score 43):

You figured out already that $\,x \bmod n\,$ gives the periodic sequence $\,(1, 2, \ldots, n-1, \color{red}{0}, 1, \ldots)\,$ then the rest is just "shifting" it to fit the desired start/end values. To match $\,(1, 2, \ldots, \color{red}{n}, 1, \ldots)\,$ for example, you need to shift $\,x \bmod n\,$ up by $\color{blue}{1}$, and $\,x\,$ down by $\color{green}{1}$ to compensate for it. So in the end you'd be getting $\,\color{blue}{1} + (x-\color{green}{1}) \bmod n\,$, and of course $\,(x-1) \bmod n = (x+n-1) \bmod n\,$.

Comment: To generalize the observations in this answer: if you want to repeat the first $p$ members of an arithmetic sequence $a_k=m(k-1)+d$, then the function you need is $m((k-1)\bmod p)+d$

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Indeed, worth pointing out.

Answer (score 39):

The $k$:th number will be:
$$[1,0,0]{\bf C}^k[1,2,3]^T$$

where ${\bf C}= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{array}\right]$

Now you can exchange the vector to the right for any ordered set of numbers you want to $\bf C$ycle through.

---

(It is actually a [***representation matrix***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) for a [***generator***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(mathematics)) of the [***cyclic group $C_3$***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) if you want to dig into some theory).

---

Now to make this a *function* of $k$, (which is actually what is asked), maybe you prefer the notation

$$k\overset{f(k)}{\longrightarrow} [1,0,0]{\bf C}^k[1,2,3]^T$$
or maybe

$$f(k)= [1,0,0]{\bf C}^k[1,2,3]^T$$

Comment: As it turns out, explicitly evaluating the matrix power and simplifying yields a remarkably simple expression: $$1-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\sin\frac{2\pi  k}{3}+2\sin^2\frac{\pi  k}{3}$$

Comment: I would argue it is not a simpler expression. Trancendental functions and irrational numbers are lots less simple computationally speaking than binary shuffles / pointer arithmetics which you can implement permutation matrices with.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician. FWIW this is the same as $ 2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sin(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JiK Better now?

Comment: I suspect @JiK means that this does not give what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Comment: @PJTraill the answers are not only supposed to help the person asking the question. They could sometimes help other people learn new things too.

Answer (score 19):

As an alternative, here is a purely trigonometric function which generates the required sequence:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}\sin(\frac 23\pi(x-2))}{\cos(\frac 23\pi(x-2))+2}+2$$

Here we have $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=1$, and so on.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JiK no perhaps not, but I thought I'd post it anyway.

Comment: @JiK is right: this does not give what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Comment: @PJTraill So what? The OP is not the only one who reads these Q/As, and this and other answers giving alternate expressions (and systematic methods for finding them) are by no means off topic. If you dispute this, you should take it up on meta instead of spamming everyone's answers.

Comment: this a good answer to a better question we couldn't think of.

Answer (score 18):

$f(x)=\left\lfloor 10^x\cdot {123\over999}\right\rfloor\mod 10$.

More generally, with $b>n>1$,
$$f(x)=\left\lfloor b^x\cdot {(123\ldots n)_b\over b^n-1}\right\rfloor\mod b.
$$

Comment: Ingenious (+1) though not too practical computationally.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I presume @JiK means that this does not give what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume we want to find a formula for the sequence
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{3,1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},1,3,3,1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},1,3,3,1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},1,3,\ldots}
\end{align*}
repeating in cycles of $6$ elements.

> The $r$-th roots of unity $\omega_j=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij}{r}\right), 0\leq j<r$ have the nice property to *filter* elements. For $r>0$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij n}{r}\right)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad r\mid n\\
> 0& \qquad otherwise
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   Therefore the sequence
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{1}{6}\sum_{j=0}^5\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ijn}{6}\right)\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}
> =(\color{blue}{1},0,0,0,0,0,\color{blue}{1},0,0,0,0,0,\color{blue}{1},\ldots)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   generates a $1$ at each $6$-th position and $0$ otherwise and multiplication with $3$ gives a sequence with $3$ at each $6$-th position and $0$ otherwise.
>
> Appropriately shifting of (1) can be used to generate a $1$ on each $6$-th position shifted by $k$ positions with $0\leq k < 6$. Multiplication with $3,1$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ and adding all these terms provides the wanted sequence.

*Hint:* Some instructive examples can be found in H.S. Wilf's book *[generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)*, (2.4.5) to (2.4.9).

Comment: For that portion of the audience allergic to complex numbers .... these can be done with trigonometric functions instead of complex exponentials.

Comment: @GEdgar I guess it comes down to whether people are more allergic to complex numbers or otherwise hard-to-remember compound angle formulae.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JiK: This answer introduces a systematic way to build sequences $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n,a_1,a_2,...)$ consisting of repeated sub-sequences. All the more it provides a systematic way to build sequences $(1,2,3,...,n,1,2,...) which was OPs question.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer The question is "How would one come to _this result_ in a more systematic way?" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned composition. You've identified that you need to shift the range

$$f_1(x) = x - 1$$

then take the value *modulo* $n$

$$f_2(x) = x \mod n$$

and finally shift the result again

$$f_3(x) = x + 1$$

The function you want is just the composition $f = f_3 \circ f_2\circ f_1$.

Comment: And it looks like a conjugation if you write it $f = f_1^{-1} \circ f_2 \circ f_1$.

Comment: I like this answer best because it actually gives a systematic way to convert the function $x \bmod 3$ into the function that was desired.

Answer (score 6):

Let be $\omega\in\Bbb C$, $\omega^3 = 1$, $\omega\ne 1$. $\omega^n$ gives:
$$\omega^0 = 1,$$
$$\omega^1 = \omega,$$
$$\omega^2 = \omega^{-1},$$
$$\omega^3 = 1,$$
$$\cdots$$
"But I want $1,2,3,\dots$!" Solution: compose with a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) $P$ s.t.
$$P(1) = 1,\qquad P(\omega) = 2,\qquad P(\omega^{-1}) = 3.$$
Now,
$$P(\omega^0) = 1,$$
$$P(\omega^1) = 2,$$
$$P(\omega^2) = 3,$$
$$P(\omega^3) = 1,$$
$$\cdots$$
This trick will work for any periodic sequence.

Comment: This does not give what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Answer (score 5):

The function

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x, & \text{if } x \leq n\\
f(x-n), & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

maps the set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to the sequence $\{1, 2, \ldots, n, 1, 2, \ldots, n, \ldots\}$. Is this way "more systematic" to you?

Comment: I created a answer very much like yours but yours is both more general and correct.

Comment: This does not give what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Comment: @PJTraill You're absolutely right. I apparently didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are many answers to this actually, for instance
$$ f(n) = n + 1 - 3\lfloor n/3\rfloor $$
(assuming $\mathbb Z^+$ starts with $0$).

How to come to this? The basic idea is that $s(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the sawtooth function with range $[0,1)$. Then $ns(x/n)$ is the same function scaled $n$ times in both directions, i.e., it's the sawtooth function with range $[0,n)$. However, you need range $[1,n+1)$, so that's the “$+1$” part.

Comment: This is basically the definition of mod function. $a \mod b = a-b\lfloor{a\over b}\rfloor$ :) except it's shifted by one horizontally and then verticall

Comment: @KKZiomek I don't say it is not :-) And I believe that this view is self-explanatory, that's why I consider it good for educational purposes.

Comment: This does not give (or only indirectly gives) what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Comment: @PJTraill Well, that's true, but I still think that the way I show is a related point that could be useful in grasping the whole topic.

Answer (score 4):

f(x) = ((x−1) mod n) + 1

Step 1: You want a function with a period of n, i.e. it repeats every n numbers.  Then necessarily you are modding something by n.  g(x) = h(x) mod n
Step 2:  You want the function to reset after every nth number.  But the nature of modular division is that it resets on every nth number, not after every nth number.  So you necessarily have to subtract 1 before performing modular division.  h(x) = x - 1.  g(h(x)) = (x - 1) mod n.  This is a horizontal shift, akin to an x-intercept.
Step 3: You want the function to vary from 1 to n, but the nature of modular division is to vary from 0 to n-1.  So you have to add 1 to each term after the modular division.  i(x) = g(h(x)) + 1 = ((x - 1) mod n) + 1.  This is a vertical shift, akin to a y-intercept.
Unnecessary step 4: If you wanted each term to be a multiple of 1 through n, i.e. (3, 6, 9, ... 3n), you would perform multiplication last.  I.e. j(x) = 3 * i(g(h(x)) = 3 * (((x - 1) mod n) + 1).  This is an amplitude shift, akin to a slope.

Comment: ▲ A useful description of the effects of the various steps involved in reaching the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In group theory, the modulus function is often taken to be a function from **Z** to **Z**/n**Z**. That is, the output is not an integer, but the equivalence class of integers that have the same remainder when divided by n. E.g. 1->{...-5,-2,1,4,7...}. In computer science, on the other hand, modulus functions generally give a particular representative of the equivalence class, more specifically whatever representative lies in [0,n-1]. You're trying to instead get the representative that lies in [1,n]. Note that this differs only in how 0+n**Z** is treated; the standard function sends it to 0, but you want it sent to n. So if you were writing a program, one option would be to simply do `output = (k mod n)` then `if output==0: output=n`. However, that's somewhat of an inelegant solution.

A solution that is in some sense more elegant is to realize that you want your output range shifted up one. If you do `output = (k mod n)+1`, then instead of your output ranging from 0 to n-1, your output will be 1 to n. However, this shifts not only the output range, but also what each input goes to; 1 goes to 2 instead of 1, 2 goes to 3, etc. If you subtract 1 before taking the modulus, then this will cancel out with the adding 1 afterwards. The exception to this will be multiples of n; by subtracting 1, you get to n-1, then when you add 1 afterwards, you get to n, instead of 0.

Your formula adds n-1 instead of subtracting 1, but since (n-1) mod n = -1, this amounts to the same thing.

One way of visualizing this is imagining n tick marks in a circle. There's a tick mark labeled 1, a tick mark labeled 2, etc., up to n-1. But when you get to n, the tick mark is labeled 0, and then at n+1 you're back at the tick mark labeled 1. What if you want your output for n to be n, instead of 0? Well, you can think of there being a "drop" between the tick mark labeled n-1 and the one labeled 0; between those two tick marks, the output drops from n-1 to 0. You want to move n over to before this drop, and make the drop to instead be between n and n+1. So to move n to before the drop, you subtract 1; this shifts n over to before the drop. But now you need to add 1 back. The addition and subtraction cancel out in the sense that you end up in the same equivalence class (remember, the equivalence class for both 0 and n is {-2n,-n,0,n,2n...}), but by doing the subtraction before doing the modulus, and the addition after, you end up with a different representative.

More generally, if you want to shift j numbers from the beginning to the end, you can do (k-j) mod n + j. For instance, k mod 12 would take k to between 0 and 11, but (k-3) mod 12 + 3 will take k to between 3 and 14. To go the other way, you reverse the addition and subtraction; (k+3) mod 12 - 3 will take k to between -3 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe those with allergies to both complex numbers and trigonometry are more tolerant to homogeneous coordinate transforms?

$$
f(k) = [1 \ 0\  2]
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12 & -\frac{\sqrt3}2 & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt3}2 &-\frac12 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^k
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ \frac{\sqrt3}3 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This does not give what the questioner asked for, namely a systematic approach to arriving at the formula they themself found, i.e. $ ( ( x - 1 ) \bmod n ) + 1 $.

Answer (score 2):

Your only problem is that you're counting up from one.  If you started counting from zero, then $$f(x) = x \bmod 3$$ would do the job, generating the output sequence $0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,\dots$ when applied to the input sequence $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,\dots$.

But if you *insist* on one-based counting, then you simply need to shift the input down by one, and the output correspondingly up by one, as in $$f(x) = ((x-1) \bmod 3) + 1.$$  This will generate the output sequence $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\dots$ when applied to the input sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\dots$.