# Trigonometric Generation Function for $1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 18 \cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm looking for a trig function (that is, I want a non-"modular arithmetic" answer) to generate $1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 18...$,
for an example see [Function which creates the sequence 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678895/function-which-creates-the-sequence-1-2-3-1-2-3/2679993#2679993)

Comment: this question makes no sense, can you give an example?

Comment: @jimjim Sure: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2679993/743045

It seems to me that it could be expressed as a trig function instead of something more exotic.

Comment: your request to sum the numbers with the example you have given is incorrect, what is the general term? what is the motivation for this question? your tags do not apply to this question, I am not voting you down, but this question is too far from being quality question.

Comment: It seems pretty simple in principle. The sequence is: $1+0, 1+2, 3+3, 6+1, 7+2.$

Comment: What do you mean by "purely trigonometric"?  Do you mean trigonometric functions adjoined to algebraic expressions?

Comment: @BrianTung , JimJim edited\wrote it that way. I mean using trig functions not $mod$ or such like.

Comment: @BrianTung, yes, adjoined is fine

Comment: Starting at $n=0$ if we subtract $2n+1$ you get:

$$0,0,1,0,0,1,\dots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at $a_0=1$ if we subtract $2n+1$ from $a_n$ you get:

$$(a_n-2n-1)_n=(0,0,1,0,0,1,\cdots)$$

This can be written as:

$$a_n-2n-1 = \frac13\left(1+\cos\frac{2(n+1)\pi}3 +\cos\frac{4(n+1)\pi}3\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you give the final result in terms of $f(n)$ in other words: $f(n)=$"function". Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I missed the $+1$. Thanks!